# Node JS: Effective way to separate segemets of raw json from page source such that it is easier to group keys and values into array

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

essentially, the page source in which my request is getting is very muddled, however there is one particular section I am most interested in which is more organised and has the data in which I intend to group into an array.

It comes under the header of

```
items: [
        {
    plu: "000000",
    description: "test",
    colour: "grey",
    unitPrice: "110.00",
    category: "",
    categoryId: "",
    sale: false,
    brand: "xxxx",
    ownbrand: false,
    exclusive: false,
    onlineexlusive: false
}
```

How will I be able to group all the items to follow under within this "items" section into an array and then extract the plu separately. Sorry, I'm new to node!

Comment: The json data that is obtained from the `GET` request is within a variable called "body"

Comment: anyone got a starting point?